# jQuery Data - getting elem id?

Tags: jquery

In jQuery 1.3.2 - `jQuery('#id').data(elem)` returned the `id` ? I'm wondering how to do the same thing using jQuery 1.6.2 ?

Understanding now is that it returns the `object` as opposed to the `id` as it was in jQuery 1.3.2 ?

How can I get the `id` ?

Edit: sorry for not clarifying - the `.data key/value pair` - because I'm upgrading from 1.3.2 and `.data(elem)` is no longer returning the ID - and im unsure how to get it using 1.6.2 ?

Comment: Why not give a full example of what you want instead of little bits of code? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question shows:

```
jQuery('#id').data(elem)
```

But I assume this does not reflect what you actually want.

I'm guessing you're really doing:

```
jQuery.data( elem )
```

As in:

```
var elem = $('#test');

alert( $.data( elem ) );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Xd3km/

...which (in `jQuery 1.3.2`) *does not give the ID of the element*, but rather the ID representing the element in `jQuery.cache`.

I'm pretty sure you can't do this as of `jQuery 1.4`. Furthermore, I'm not sure why this number would be useful. Especially since the structure of `jQuery.cache` is meant for internal use, and is subject to change.

Doing `jQuery.data( elem )` now gives you the data object associated with that element in `jQuery.cache`. It should provide anything that is really useful to you.

Comment: thanks :) exactly the `roundabout` explanation I was looking for :) One question however - how to access the data from the ( elem ) ? i.e. if I have jQuery('#id').data('test', []); ?

Comment: `jQuery('#id').data('test');` will give you the Array.

Answer (score 1):

you are expecting element id by using `jQuery('#id').data(elem)`. you pass the element id as jQuery selector and again expecting the id. so what is the purpose of this.
if you really want use `.attr("id");` or `.prop("id");`

Comment: Not an answer. The selector is for the example purpose only. See my answer to see a more real practical use.

Comment: +1 to get you back to zero.  There is nothing wrong with this answer as those are both valid ways to get an element's id.

Comment: Except it seems like he doesn't want the element's ID @Dennis

Comment: Folks...if you disagree with an answer then down vote, please don't flag to say that it's wrong. Moderators are not the arbiters of whether an answer is technically correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bit of code:

```
jQuery('#id').prop('id');
```

## [jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/3e5YD/1/).

---

If you wanted to get the `key` for the `jQuery.data()` method, I'm afraid it's no longer possible. As there are multiple keys and multiple values. There might be a funky object solution I'm not aware of, but as for the manual says, not possible.

Comment: I am actually wanting http://jquery14.com/day-01/jquery-14#backwards - if you notice jQuery.data(elem) - "jQuery.data(elem) no longer returns an id, it returns the element’s object cache instead.". How do I get the `id` ?

Comment: By ID do you mean the Element's ID? or the .data key/value pair key?

Comment: sorry for not clarifying - the `.data key/value pair` - because I'm upgrading from 1.3.2 and `.data(elem)` is no longer returning the ID - and im unsure how to get it using 1.6.2 ?